# Django: Do something when user goes to a listview page

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a notifications page that collects notification actions when someone does something. I want to be able to run a command on my notificaitons model to set all of my objects to read when the user goes to the page. How can I do that when I'm using a class based list view?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by `able to run a command on my notificaitons model to set all of my objects to read` ?

Comment: Have a look at django signals

Comment: I want to run Notification.object.filter(id=request.id).update(status='read'). Can you execute a signal on a list view? The model isn't ever saved and so I don't see how that would work